# Upgrade Python SQlite3 module with SQlite binaries of Centos7 (local machine)

Tags: sqlite, upgrade, centos7, python-3.7

After looking around for a while, I couldn't find an answer to my problem. In my Centos 7 machine I have an upgraded version of SQlite:
`usr/bin/sqlite3`

Now my Python still has the default installed version.

```
import sqlite3
sqlite3.sqlite_version
```

> '3.7.17'

How can I upgrade it or change the path to the Centos binaries?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you upgrade the shared library too? That's what python uses. Upgrading just the sqlite command line shell isn't going to do anything for that.

Comment: Nope, I didn't what do you mean by shared library? What directory/file should I look at?
Is there command to upgrade the shared library?

Answer (score 1):

Solved:
Instead of the binaries I took the full installation

Download latest sqlite3 from official site. (https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)

Unapack. 
tar xvfz sqlite....tar.gz

Go to the unpacked dir. cd sqlite-....

./configure

make

make install

Now you successfully install updated sqlite3. Now fire this command sudo LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./configure --enable-optimizations

Open your activate file of virtual environment (e.g., venv/bin/activate) and add this line top of the file... export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"